# Let $X_S=X_1+X_2$ what is the pdf $f_{X_S|X_1,X_2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables with pdf $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$.

Let
$$
X_S=X_1+X_2.
$$

It is well known that the pdf of  $X_s$ is given by
$$
f_{X_S}(x)= E [f_{X_1}(x-X_2)]=E [f_{X_2}(x-X_1)]
$$

However, I am having a hard time to derive the conditional and joint pdfs.

For example, suppose I want to find $f_{X_1,X_2\mid X_S}$, then by Bayes rule 
\begin{align}
f_{X_1,X_2\mid X_S}= \frac{f_{X_1,X_2,X_S}}{f_{X_S}}= \frac{f_{X_S\mid X_1,X_2} f_{X_1,X_2}}{f_{X_S}}= \frac{f_{X_S\mid X_1,X_2} f_{X_1}f_{X_2}}{f_{X_S}}
\end{align}
where the last equation is by independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I have a difficulting understanding what $f_{X_S|X_1,X_2}$ should be?

$X_s$ is completely determined by $X_1,X_2$ so I was thinking it should be either zero or one. Something like this
\begin{align}
f_{X_S\mid X_1,X_2}(x_s\mid x_1,x_2)=1_{x: x_1+x_2=x}(x)
\end{align}

Is this a correct way of thinking about it?

Comment: The conditional PDF $f_{X_S|X_1,X_2}$ does not exist since $X_S$ is a function of $(X_1,X_2)$. The conditional distribution of $X_S$ conditionally on $(X_1,X_2)$ is the Dirac measure at $X_1+X_2$. The conditional PDF $f_{X_1,X_2|X_S}$ does not exist since, conditionally on $X_S=x$, $(X_1,X_2)$ is almost surely on the line of equation $x_1+x_2=x$, which has measure zero. (All these are direct consequences of the definitions, and it seems you are severely lacking some...)